# "Expected an identifier" error in vscode when stdlib.h is included

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a small C program that has a header file with functions for determining min, max, sum etc of an array of floats. Everything is working as intended and it compiles and runs but VScode is giving me the error shown in the image below, the error only appeared once I included stdlib.h, and I included that to be able to use the exit function when there is an invalid input. Anybody know why I'm getting this error? Is it a problem with a setting in VScode since it's still running and working or is there something wrong with my code.
Thanks!

Here is the header file:

```
//Include guard
#ifndef AGGREGATE_HEADER
#define AGGREGATE_HEADER

float min(float a[], int size);
float max(float a[], int size);
float sum(float a[], int size);
float avg(float a[], int size);
float pseudo_avg(float a[], int size);

#endif
```

and here are my functions:

```
#include "aggregate.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float min(float a[], int size) {

  //Check for invalid input
  if (a == NULL || size < 0) {
    printf("FATAL ERROR in line %d\n", __LINE__);
    exit(0);
  }

  //Set the first value to the current minimum
  float current_min = a[0];
  //Loop through all of the array elements starting after the 1st one
  for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
    //Check if current index is less than the current minimum
    if (a[i] < current_min) {
      current_min = a[i]; //Update min
    }
  }

  return current_min;
}

float max(float a[], int size) {

  //Check for invalid input
  if (a == NULL || size < 0) {
    printf("FATAL ERROR in line %d\n", __LINE__);
    exit(0);
  }

  //Set the first value to the current max
  float current_max = a[0];
  //Loop through all of the array elements starting after the 1st one
  for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
    //Check if current index is less than the current max
    if (a[i] > current_max) {
      current_max = a[i]; //Update max
    }
  }

  return current_max;
}
```

lastly, here is my main file

```
#include "aggregate.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  float arr[] = {1, 4, 5, 6, -1};

  float min1 = min(arr, 5);
  printf("%f", min1);
  printf(", ");

  float max1 = max(arr, 5);
  printf("%f", max1);
  printf(", ");

  float sum1 = sum(arr, 5);
  printf("%f", sum1);
  printf(", ");

  float avg1 = avg(arr, 5);
  printf("%f", avg1);
  printf(", ");

  float pavg = pseudo_avg(arr, 5);
  printf("%f", pavg);

  return (0);
}
```

The error message is shown in the image below:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4k6S.png)

Comment: What toolchain are you using? If you're going to choose ids `min` and `max` to include in your program, and you're using a toolchain like MSVC that defines those ids as macros, you need to disable the macros. In the case of MSVC the disablement is done by defining `NOMINMAX` before including *any* standard headers, ideally on your compile-flags as a `-D` to ensure all source files pick it up before heading into any preprocessing step.

Comment: ..or try renaming these to `my_min`/`my_max` or similar and see if it helps.

Comment: Do not post error messages as images. Put them as text in the posted question, and show which line of code they apply to.

Comment: `aggregate.c` is missing three functions: `avg`, `pseudo_avg` and `sum`.

Comment: Sorry, I can not reproduce the behavior.

Comment: This is probably because (e.g.) `min` is defined in `stdio.h` [or something it includes] as a macro (e.g. `#define min(a,b) (a < b) ? a : b`). After the `#include`, put: `#ifdef min #error min is macro #endif` and see what happens. Leave that off and compile with `cc -o foo.i -E foo.c`. Then examine `foo.i`. Then compile with `cc -c foo.i`. That should show what is going on.